# ReactJS listen/watch for DOM changes

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs, bootstrap-carousel

I'm having a simple Carousel in ReactJS application which runs fine. However, I'm trying to render the slide's content only if it is (hasClass) active, otherwise `<myComponent/>` fires three times on load.

What is the correct way in ReactJS to listen for DOM (div) changes and listen for its class changes and when it is `.active` then render the content?

Code:

```
    render() {
        return (
            <div class="carousel slide carousel-fade " >
                <div class="carousel-inner"  >
                    <div class="item active" ref="slide">
                        {/*if class is active render the content, else is null*/}
                        <myComponent/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item" ref="slide">
                        {/*if class is active render the content, else is null*/}
                        <myComponent/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item" ref="slide">
                        {/*if class is active render the content, else is null*/}
                        <myComponent/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Many thanks

Comment: Which carousel library are you using?

Comment: I would not suggest to listen to the class name, but rather to use the bootstrap-carousel event listener [documented here](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/#events).